# how to get nonce value from braintree using c# and asp.net

Tags: braintree

I want get the nonce value from braintree. 
I can get the client token very easily but how can i get the nonce value from braintree in asp.net c#.

any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your client is set up correctly as shown [here](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/start/hello-client/javascript/v2#setup), it will fetch the payment method nonce from the Braintree servers and make it available on your servers as shown [here](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/start/hello-server/dotnet#receive-a-payment-method-nonce-from-your-client). If you still have trouble retrieving the nonce, I recommend reaching out to [Braintree support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/) for help.